# Is there a Cocoa/Unix API into macOS' "Memorable" password generator?

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix, passwords

It seems like the easiest way to bring it up is through the "Users and Groups" preference panel, but if I could quickly generate them on the CLI or with a tiny app, that'd be much nicer.

Talkin' about this little guy:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: Yes, it's in the SecurityFoundation framework, it's simple and easy to use, and Anders Bergh has wrapped it up nicely in a command line utility:

https://github.com/anders/pwgen/blob/master/sf-pwgen.m